# how to download turbo c++ in DOSBOX?

Tags: c++

[image: enter link description here]

I'm not be able to download TURBO C++. It says it is already extracted.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju The reasons behind why people do or use different things doesn't change or modify the question in any way. If something is supported, even if it isn't recommended or even if it is deprecated, the question is legitimate.

Comment: @Zzzach... Still — is DosBox on-topic?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju I'll agree with you that dosbox by itself is offtopic. If this is an issue with dosbox interacting with Ubuntu in a way that is different than Windows or Mac, then I'd be on-topic. But you're right, seems this question is just about dosbox (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change directory to "Desktop" by `cd Desktop` and then to tc3 by `cd tc3`.

Comment: plz, can you be more specific?

Comment: thnx ..but after almost 60% process,i stucked...TC.exe is not able to open in dosbox..dosbox is just coming for 2 sec after clicking on tc.exe...plz,suggest what to do?